# mySQL voting system SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a voting system and the tables look like this:

```
answers
-----------
int id
text content

results
-----------
int id
int answers_id
```

I want a select so i can see the answer and the number of responds even if there are no votes(results). 
I tried something like this:

```
SELECT 
count(results.answers_id), answers.content
from answers
left outer join results
on answers.id = results.answers_id
group by results.answers_id
```

But it doesn't get the answers with 0 votes(results).

Comment: COUNT(column) doesn't count NULL (no vote). Use count(*) to count all - including null!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
SELECT count(results.answer_id), answers.content
from answers left outer join results on answers.id = results.answer_id
group by answers.content;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT
count(result.answers_id) as acount, answers.content
from answers
left inner join results
on answers.id = acount
```

Comment: I don't think If that will work, shouldn't be added group by clause if aggregate function is used in select clause?

Answer (score 0):

Use subquery

```
SELECT a.*,
   ( SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM results r
     WHERE a.id = r.answers_id
   )
FROM answers a
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, grouping on the Id of the answer.

```
SELECT 
COUNT(results.answers_id) AS NumberOfAnswers, answers.content
from answers
left join results
on answers.id = results.answers_id
group by answers.id
```

To make sure you dont have 2 rows with same content, then `group by answers.content`

```
    SELECT 
    COUNT(results.answers_id) AS NumberOfAnswers, answers.content
    from answers
    left join results
    on answers.id = results.answers_id
    group by answers.content
```

Answer (score 0):

use `Ifnull` and also in your group by statement change it to `answers.content`

```
SELECT 
IFNULL(count(results.answers_id),0), answers.content
from answers
left outer join results
on answers.id = results.answers_id
group by answers.content
```

Answer (score 0):

I think solution is to use [IFNULL](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-ifnull/)

```
SELECT IFNULL(COUNT(r.answers_id), 0), 
       a.content
FROM   answers AS a
LEFT JOIN results AS r ON a.id = r.answers_id
GROUP BY r.answers_id
```